# Postbacktrigger control within asyncpostbacktrigger control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, triggers, updatepanel

Hi guys we have following structure in one of our project's pages:

```
  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="up1" runat="server">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="tabContainer" EventName="ActiveTabChanged"  />
      </Triggers>

    <ContentTemplate>


        <cc1:TabContainer ID="tabContainer" runat="server" Visible="false" ActiveTabIndex="0" AutoPostBack="true" OnActiveTabChanged="BtnTrigger_Click">
            <cc1:TabPanel ID="tab1" runat="server" HeaderText="tab1">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <uc:userControlFirst ID="uc1" runat="server"  />
                    <uc:userControlSecond ID="uc2" runat="server"/>                                                  
                </ContentTemplate>
            </cc1:TabPanel>....
       </ContentTemplate>
       </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

We want to update updatepanel everytime user changes tab. The problem is that within uc2 control, we have gridview with linkbuttons to download report (.xlsx) and because uc2 is inside control which is asyncpostback trigger, everytime we click on linkbutton, updatepanel updates instead of whole page, so we aren't able to download reports.

Previously when tabContainer wasn't asyncpostbactrigger, we could register gridview as postback control by:

```
ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).RegisterPostBackControl(this.gvInsertionHistory);
```

but unfortunately it stopped working.

Is there any way to register those linkbuttons or even whole gridview or uc2 as postback control even though they are inside asyncpostbackcontrol?

And whats the reason of using EventName attribute? It is set for `ActiveTabChanged` but updatepanel is updated everytime we click something inside tabContainer.

I've tried also add uc2 as PostbackTrigger in markup but it looks that it isn't possible/allowed. Setting `childrenAsTrigger` to false didn't help too.

I will be grateful for any ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you get any deeper into this, try a **Querystring** based approach by rewriting your download buttons to links with Queryparamters - rather than postback buttons - to export your xlsx. This will always **result in a full page load** (as long as you're not using frames). Generate something like this:

```
<a href="?ID=1&Format=xlsx">download</a>
```

and in the Page_Load check

```
if (Request.Querystring["Format"] == "xlsx")
{
  //Response.Write(...render xlsx method)
}
```

**Edit:** you could even `target="_blank"` the link to keep the current page view as it is

Comment: Hi, It probably will work but I've found even simpler solution. I've just set  PostbackUrl="<page on which control is>" on LinkButton and it makes postback, but didn't refresh whole page. The 2nd think that we've figure out was that our asyncpostbactrigger wasn't necessary cause tabcontainer is within updatepanel.